# vmware python sdk get single vm/template without pulling all the vm's

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I'm using vmware python sdk (https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi). Is there any way via rest api's, python or **anyway** to just list vm based on filters for getting single vm based on name or uuid, without listing all vm's and then searching.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, but only for search by UUID:

[find_by_uuid](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/find_by_uuid.py)